# Flex : Nested data grids?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4.5

- What is the best approach to create a nested grids ?

*//all ideas will be more than appreciated :)*

Comment: It is doable.  We've done it on a current project with an AdvancedDataGrid that extends to show another DataGrid.  But honestly, my best suggestion is try to avoid this approach.  I personally find it a bit confusing to use and layout is a nightmare.  I'm not sure if this question is answerable as written; as it is too generic.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to approach it that's why it might look a bit generic, anyway it is strictly specific - using one gird as item renderer on another grid ( for instance ).

Comment: The question, as written, is strictly related to Memory Footprint of nested grids; and I believe the topic of memory footprint isn't addressable without a code review pr possibly some profiler work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it !

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_10.html

In the Adobe documentation about Advanced Data Grid is mentioned about a piechart which can span on entire row, i just switched with a grid on the renderer and i got what i were searching for. :)

Thanks for the hints to everyone :)

Comment: I hope this save someone's head-to-wall banging :)

Answer (score 0):

The answers can be fairly large as a lot of considerations have to be accounted for, first it is best to understand which data grids you propose to use? Spark or MX "Yuck" then it would be important to understand if the child and parent data grids share columns.

Better if you give a more context to provide a concrete answer

Comment: i don't think i need to explain this since one of the tags is Flex 4.5 and by default it requiring Spark components.